# How to align a H1 to an image

Tags: html, css

I have this block of code, but the H1 is very slightly higher than the image. Is this a way I can bring this perfectly inline?

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items:center;">
    <h1 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; color: #333; padding: 0.6rem;">
    <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Red_square.svg" width="40" height="40" /> My Text</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please include a [mre].

Comment: I mean, why do you ask us if it is working? Can't you test it yourself?

Comment: Can't see it working and can't see what you want. More details please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move image from the outside of the H1 tag.
Try this one!

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items:center;">
   <img style="vertical-align: middle;"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Red_square.svg" width="40" height="40" />
   <h1 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; color: #333; padding: 0.6rem;">My Text</h1> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image inside the h1 was the problem. The container div was already applying the correct styles you wanted.

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items:center;">
    <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Red_square.svg" width="40" height="40" />
    <h1 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; color: #333; padding: 0.6rem;">My Text</h1> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<figure>
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Use caption for the alignment along picture